# there a more effective/elegant way to config parsing?

Tags: php, config, ini

example:

```
$CONF = parse_ini_file('cfg.ini', true);
$EmailUN = $CONF['EM']['key01'];
$EmailPW = $CONF['EM']['key02'];
$EmailTO = $CONF['EM']['key03'];
$SMSAPI = $CONF['SMS']['key01'];
$SMSUN = $CONF['SMS']['key02'];
$SMSPW = $CONF['SMS']['key03'];
$SMSNUM = $CONF['SMS']['key04'];
```

is there a more effective/elegant way to import this data? i want to learn best practices while im still learning. i dont want to fill up the whole top of my php doc with objects calling for keys. if this is a duplicate i apologize in advance.

Comment: Well if you don't want to make use of additional variables, you could always just use their values directly.

Comment: if you mean to just add that info my config is holding directly into my source that is defeating the purpose of my config. however if not i may have misunderstood and could you please explain better?

Comment: Well assuming you are using the variables to do something like `mail($EmailTO, 'Subject', 'Message')`, you could instead do something like `mail($CONF['EM']['key03'], 'Subject', 'Message')`.

Comment: that is an option and i just tested it and worked, but is this best practice?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're trying to do, and what your preference is. For example, I never use a `config.ini` to control things like my E-mail and SMS settings, and usually store those as `GLOBALS` in a configuration file that get imported when necessary. But again, it's personal preference. Defining variables creates more lines of code, but creates shorter lines, and makes for *much* easier updating in the future. I'd say your approach is fine.

Comment: So defining them in top of my php doc is ok to do? I’m trying to keep all my usernames and passwords out of my source completely. I don’t want to do something that is frowned upon if it’s really supposed to be done a certain way like common core math now days....

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be a helper function that accesses your configuration.

If for example you wanted to access your configuration like this:

```
config('SMS.key01');
```

You could define the `config` function as:

```
function config(string $key)
{
    static $config = parse_ini_file('cfg.ini', true);

    $curr = $config;
    foreach(explode('.', $key) as $segment) {
        if(!isset($curr[$segment]) {
            return null;
        } else if(is_array($curr[$segment])) {
            $curr = $curr[$segment];
            continue;
        }

        return $curr[$segment];
    }
}
```

The above is a minimal example roughly based on Laravel's `config` and [`array_get`](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Arr.php#L278) helpers. Your helper function would likely need to be implemented differently in the context of your application or framework.

The main advantage of this approach is that all of the implementation details of how your configuration is stored and accessed is contained within the function. What you are doing right now bleeds low level implementation details into the rest of your code.

Comment: noob question: where would this function be declared? once declared i would use it this way "$mail->addAddress =  config('SMS.key01');" ? im using phpmailer for my testing of everything.

Comment: There's no simple answer to that question without knowing more about your application (are you using composer? Do you have an autoloader? etc). The function just needs to be declared before you can use it.

Comment: i am now using composer. wasnt before now somewhat familiar with it. i feel like i opened a giant can of worms. yes i have an autoloader now. upon looking up laravel 5 config files and how to use them...umm yeah i feel like the person who wrote this site had not a care in the world about organizing or security in mind. if i can declare it inside composer and its best practice ill do that...rather learn best practice now then later..